# What is the difference between these two codes and why are they giving different outputs?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

**Problem Statement:** Given the head of a linked list and a value x, partition it such that all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x.

You should preserve the original relative order of the nodes in each of the two partitions.

**First Code that provides correct output**

```
ListNode* partition(ListNode* head, int x) {
        ListNode* small = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode* large = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode* smallhead = small;
        ListNode* largehead = large;

        while(head) {
            if(head->val<x) {
                small->next = head;
                small = small->next;
                head = head->next;
                small->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
                large->next = head;
                large = large->next;
                head = head->next;
                large->next = NULL;
            }
        }
        small->next = largehead->next;

        return smallhead->next;
    }
```

**Second Code that provides wrong output**

```
ListNode* partition(ListNode* head, int x) {
        ListNode* small = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode* large = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode* smallhead = small;
        ListNode* largehead = large;

        while(head) {
            if(head->val<x) {
                small->next = head;
                small = small->next;
                small->next = NULL;
                head = head->next;
            }
            else {
                large->next = head;
                large = large->next;
                large->next = NULL;
                head = head->next;
            }
        }
        small->next = largehead->next;

        return smallhead->next;
    }
```

**And this is the defination of ListNode Structure**

```
struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
```

I just want to know why these two codes show different output.

Comment: In the `if` block, the `small` pointer becomes the same as the `head` pointer (the statement `small = small->next;` really is doing `small = head`). In the wrong version of the code, you first set its `next` field to `nullptr`, and then move `head` to it, making it `nullptr`. That's not what you want to happen. You want `head` to move to the next node **before** you break that link.

Comment: But honestly, this becomes trivial when you use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Draw boxes and arrows with pen(cil) and paper and trace through the code.

Comment: You should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Answer (score 3):

After

```
small->next = head;
small = small->next;
```

`small` and `head` have the same value therefore

```
small->next = NULL;
head = head->next;
```

will always set `head` to `NULL` as the first line sets `head->next` to `NULL`.

```
head = head->next;
small->next = NULL;
```

Works because it moves `head` to `next` before setting `next` to `NULL`.